# incrementing a $_GET variable

Tags: global-variables

How do I get this $_GET['ago'] variable to increment by 1

```
public function __construct($future=false) {
    $GLOBALS['twd_helper']=&$this;
}   
public function query_string($add, $remove=null) {
    $qs_data = array();
    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $qs_data);
    $qs_data = array_merge($qs_data, $add);
    if ($remove) {
        foreach($remove as $key) {
            if (isset($qs_data[$key])) {
                unset($qs_data[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return http_build_query($qs_data);
}


public function filter_overnight () {
    if (isset($_GET['tod']) && $_GET['tod'] == 'overnight') {
        $overnight = $_GET['overnight'];
    }

    if (($_GET['ago'])) {
        $_GET['ago'] ? $_GET['ago']++ : $_GET['ago'] = 0;
    }

}
```

I want to change my URL to increase by 1 each time its clicked
guide?ago=1
guide?ago=2
guide?ago=3
etc

Answer (score 0):

In the html, just do this:

```
<a href="my_link.php?ago=<? echo (int)$_GET['ago'] + 1 ?>">Link Text</a>
```

Your filter_overnight function is a bit odd too - I think it could be made more readable:

```
if ($_GET['ago'])
{
    $_GET['ago'] = (int)$_GET['ago'] + 1;
}
else
{
    $_GET['ago'] = 0;
}
```

Or with the ternary:

```
$_GET['ago'] = ($_GET['ago']) ? (int)$_GET['ago'] + 1 : 0
```

Without seeing the whole code, I'm not sure why filter_overnight is incrementing $_GET['ago'], but at a glance it appears to put an undocumented side effect into the function by changing a global value (which would also render the increment in the <a> pointless).  The superglobals in PHP can be dangerous things - I find it best to treat them as immutable and copy values out of them vs working on them directly.

Comment: Possibly - but I see that you already did so in yet another question on the same topic.  It's better to revise your original question to make it clearer, not post it again.